# Creating a new tag?

Tags: support, tags

In the comments for [this question,](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2425/what-tools-are-available-for-world-building) John Smithers and justkt asked me to create a Scrivener tag and write up the tag info.

I am fairly new to Stack Exchange and have not a clue how to go about this. I don't even know if this is the right place to ask this question — I see references to "Stack Exchange Overflow," but I don't know what that is or if it's relevant.

I have read the FAQs for both Writers and Meta and I don't see this covered. Could someone either give me some direction or point me to the appropriate place where the directions currently live? Much obliged.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhh!

Comment: John, if you were just joking, I apologize and I'll delete the question. justkt is a moderator and seemed to be serious. I am not trying to step on any toes here.

Comment: You will never finish a book, when you avoid stepping on any toes. Just let me scream and ignore me. Everyone else is doing it also ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tag is valid.  We have a software tag, and if we expect Scrivener questions we ought to have a tag for them (though being a mod doesn't give me extra weight to my vote, so anyone can disagree).

To create a tag, just type the tag.  You have to have 150 reputation (this shoots up to 1500 when we leave beta) or more to do so.

If you do create a tag, please add information to the Tag Wiki while you're at it.

Comment: I have sufficient rep, so that's not a problem. Where do I find the Tag Wiki?

Comment: @Lauren - once you've created the tag, click on it.  Then click about the tag.  Then click "Edit Tag Wiki."

Comment: Another newbie question: I create the tag, I edit the wiki, then what? Do I start retagging questions? Do I only tag the threads which mention Scrivener in the post, not as one of the responses?

Comment: @Lauren - tagging is for the question alone, not the answer.  So any questions that are about Scrivener get the tag.

Comment: Thank you. It's now telling me I don't have the privilege of editing the tag and someone has to approve it. I will write up the tag, but how much rep does one need for that privilege?

Comment: @Lauren - to see how close you are to gaining each privilege, check out your [privileges page](http://writers.stackexchange.com/privileges).  Tag edits are different, as you have to be one of the top-voted users in the tag.  Mods can approve when there are no top-voted users in the tag, I believe.

Comment: @justkt: Okay, I have created the tag, and the main board thinks I can approve it but isn't giving me an "approve" button to approve my own edits. Which is rather meta-amusing. :)

Comment: @Lauren - I approved, but the fact that you couldn't seems to be a potential bug you might want to take to [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), the network-wide meta.  The SE team seems to see that site faster.

Comment: @justkt: I was able to approve someone else's edits. I think it's a feature rather than a bug that I can't approve my own. I'll ask if you think I ought to.

Comment: +1 for "it's a feature not a bug" :P